# Redirect users to a page when they click on back button of the browser

Tags: php, javascript, button, browser, back

Is it possible to redirect users to a page when they click on back button of the browser?
If yes then how can I achieve it?

Thanks

Comment: 1) [Don't do that](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/990530.html) 2) What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: Right now I am displaying the results of a search form on the same page. The user can even filter results using the same form - the results again appear on the same page. Now if I click on the back button the following msg is show - "Confirm Form Resubmission
This webpage requires data that you entered earlier in order to be properly displayed. You can send this data again, but by doing so you will repeat any action this page previously performed. Press Reload to resend that data and display this page." - I want to avoid it.

Comment: as @Laurent says its one of the The Top Ten Web Design Mistakes of 1999, but you can implement back button by javascript's history, which is a inbuilt function, you can check that in console. history.go(-1) will do that, for anchor tag you can use : javascript:history.back(). and for button you can use : <INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="Back" onClick="history.go(-1);">

Comment: @anita.kcx: That's better solved another way, you might look at [redirect-after-post](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)

Answer (score 6):

To avoid the "Confirm Form Resubmission" message, you could use the [PRG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern. That way, when clicking the Back button, the user will simply go back to the search form, as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with this problem for quite some time. This afternoon I have been attempting to allow a user to resubmit a form purposefully. People on the internet have posted lots of things on how to get around form submission errors, but none of it has worked for my particular situation. I finally found this message from MMK on it. His solution worked perfectly, if you have to allow a user to go back to a search or something along those lines, I would totally recommend using the GET method even if you are used to using POST. If you are unsure how to exactly, just do some searching on the internet - trust me, it is worth the time.